# Symfony4 security issue

Tags: symfony4, symfony-security

I try to create a simple login form with users created or registered thru the webapp.

This is my security.yml file

```
security:

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            http_basic: ~
            provider: our_db_provider
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

    encoders:
        App\Project\UserBundle\Entity\Users:
        algorithm: bcrypt

    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Project\UserBundle\Entity\Users:
                property: username
```

If i visit a page like /nl/admin/.. i can visit the page even when im not logged in.
the acces control fails?

Even when i try to login i got invalid credentials.. but the credentials are right..

this is my controller

```
namespace App\Project\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    public function loginAction(Request $request, AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('@ProjectUser/frontend/login/login.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }
}
```

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to "regexify" the `_locale` URI path in the access_control path, depending on how they are defined. For 2 letters only locales, you can write the access_control as following :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/[a-z]{2}/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

or if you prefer to list them, something like :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/(en|nl|de)/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

access_control paths are pure string patterns, they do not consider routing parameters...